# rpy2 through WSGI on Apache yields a subinterpreter error

Tags: python, rpy2

Using R3.6 and python 3.6.9, I can run it from the command line OK, but invoked through WSGI and Apache, my requests are never returned and I see the following error in Apache logos:

```
extern "Python": function _rinterface_cffi_api._processevents() called, but @ffi.def_extern() was not called in the current subinterpreter.  Returning 0.
```

Any ideas what this may be indicating?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this with a similar experience, compiling rpy2 (3.2.7) from source with ABI using `RPY2_CFFI_MODE=ABI python setup.py build` seemed to do the trick. Not sure why.

Comment: May be it has to do with multithreading. Speaking of which, make sure to check this in the doc: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/rinterface.html#multithreading